# mysqli_result value to variable in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Echo of `facultyname` is showing a value but `fid` is not getting value.
I want to assign value of `fid` to a variable.

```
$facultyname=$_POST['facultyname'];
echo $facultyname;

$query="SELECT fid FROM faculty WHERE fname='$facultyname'";
$fid_result=mysqli_query ($link,$query);
$finfo = mysqli_fetch_field($fid_result);
 printf("FacultyID :- %d     ",$finfo->fid);
```

Comment: You're using `fetch_field` which `Returns an object which contains field definition information` and not the value of the field. You need to use basic `mysqli_fetch`.

Comment: You might want to read up on sql injection and how to prevent it

Comment: can you give me a link because i think i is deprecated from php5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change  **field to assoc**

```
 $finfo = mysqli_fetch_field($fid_result);
```

to

```
$finfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fid_result);
```

Read - for reference

> [Fetch field](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php)
>
> [Fetch Assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: it is showing "Trying to get property of non-object in" on print statement.

Comment: dude given you the reference link.. see there how they are using mysqli_fetch_assoc and how you are using. your complete code is procedural and in between you are trying to use a array as a object. that is not possible.

Comment: i removed  " ->fid " from print statement and now it showing  value 1 for all inputs.

Comment: try **echo $finfo['fid'];**